# Unable to activate the feature while deploying the solution in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio, event-receivers, feature-activation

I tried to deploy our solution in visual studio while activating the feature it throws an error message like these

> ```
> Error 2   Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Failed to load receiver assembly Branding, Version=1.0.0.0,
> ```
>
> Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f2aaa83e584920ed" for feature
>   "Branding" (ID: 1c0ad1c9-62f4-4dcf-b092-1aec1c524e47).:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   '.Branding, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=f2aaa83e584920ed' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified. File name: Branding,
>   Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f2aaa83e584920ed'
>   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName,
>   String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder,
>   Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr
>   pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection)    at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString,
>   Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean
>   forIntrospection)    at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString)    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPFeatureDefinition.get_ReceiverObject()
>
> ```
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF. To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
> ```
>
> [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1. Note: There
>   is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
>   logging. To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> ```
>       0   0   Branding
> ```

If I rename the Feature name means it's working sometimes, but first time I deploying the solution means it throwing this error,Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Your solution might have dependency on Assembly. So try to put that assembly in GAC. It may resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi, My solution is already in GAC folder, still, it's throwing the same issue @Amit

Comment: Try removing and then adding again using Gacutil

Comment: I tried, Then also it throwing the same issue bro @Amit

Comment: This happens more than you think. To me, this error appear when I change from Release to Debug and viceversa. What I do in this cases is perform a deploy with powershell using -Force attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend try to deploy using the powershell like this

```
Add-SPSolution -LiteralPath c:\solution.wsp

Install-SPSolution -Identity solution.wsp -GACDeployment
```

If you dont want to do this then try this

- Remove feature receiver
- Clean solution
- Close Visual Studio
- Delete SharePoint project's obj folder in Windows Explorer
- Delete SharePoint project's bin folder in Windows Explorer
- Open Visual Studio and re-add feature receiver
- Start Debugging

[Check the reference here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49612/failed-to-load-receiver-assembly-when-activate-feature)

[Also check this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48636650-28cb-4905-9074-14b2b5f066e2/error-occurred-in-deployment-step-activate-features?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

Comment: I tried, Still, it's not Working @Waqas

Comment: same error? did you stop and start the SharePoint timer service on the SharePoint servers