# Event receiver attached to document library is not firing

Tags: event-receivers

Event receiver was deployed into sitecollection using powershell and site feature was activated.
Using powershell , i am able to see ER is attached to library.
However , it is not firing:
Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly 'yyy', Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

PS: While deploying ER using Visual Studio in the same sitecollection , ER is working fine

Comment: Do any of these solution helped you? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/49612/failed-to-load-receiver-assembly-when-activate-feature

Comment: Thanks . actually it did.When i was using VS to deploy it got deployed as farm solution and it worked. Seems like event receivers do not fire when deployed at sitecollection level.(misssing assembly error).